# how to prevent users from adding custom attributes in Keycloak registration?

Tags: keycloak

according to the Keycloak [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#registration-page) to add custom user attributes we can edit registration template, for example, add the following snippet to the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
       <label for="user.attributes.mobile" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">Mobile number</label>
   </div>

   <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
       <input type="text" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" id="user.attributes.mobile" name="user.attributes.mobile" value="${(register.formData['user.attributes.mobile']!'')}"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

with this, the custom attribute (`mobile`) was added to the user. but the user (unregistered user) **has full control** over these custom attributes, the user can inspect and edit the HTML page to add any other custom attribute (or edit), by changing `id` and `name`.

how to prevent users from doing this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my own previous answer in favour of this one, as there are possibilities to mitigate this:

you could either use the "declarative user profile" feature, more on that here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#defining-a-user-profile

With this feature enabled, unknown fields are not going to get evaluated/persisted, only the fields known in the profile template.

Alternatively, you can implement the [FormAction SPI](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/FormAction.java) to add your own validations. See [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#modifying-or-extending-the-registration-form) for more on that.